# Qml Combobox not closing when delegate of the listview goes out of scope

Tags: qt, combobox, qml

I have made a delegate for listview that contains **Combobox**. If I open the **Combobox** and scroll the listview, the **Combobox** popup is moving with the delegate position, that's ok. But when the delegate goes out of the listview area(Ref the sample image attached), **Combobox** popup continues to moves even out of the listview area.

How to close the **Combobox** when the corresponding delegate goes out of the listview area.

Thanks in advance...

Code goes here

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        spacing: 0
        anchors.fill: parent
        Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height * 0.4
            Image {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 10
                source: "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/cITVCAj9KJ5Hfwd5iuNDhzdB2pSrMQv2rzTl-vvg23Ifhe2qdCisZBG-MzV35y_r2zijC9X4QOpda9eHzr_hA"
            }
        }
        ListView {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height * 0.7
            model: 10
            spacing: 5
            clip: true
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: 50
                color: index % 2 == 0 ? "lightsteelblue" : "steelblue"
                Row {
                    spacing: 25
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    Label {
                        text: qsTr("%1").arg(index)
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                    ComboBox {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        model: ["a", "b", "c"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: popup_goes_outofarea_sample]

Comment: Hey! Could you change the focus of the item to `false` when an area outside the `comboBox` is pressed? I have tried replicating your issue on my desktop but the second I click the mouse elsewhere it automatically closes the `comboBox` (I am using the `import QtQuick.Controls 2.2` combobox instead of your import statements

Comment: Hi @Ldweller, If we click outside Combobox it is getting hidden. But if we get the mouse pointer outside the Combobox popup and tried to scroll mouse wheel the listview will be started moving that is how the above problem happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no particular goal to keep `ComboBox` popup opened when scrolling, then add the following property to your `ListView`:

```
highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
```

This will close `ComboBox` popup when `ListView` is being scrolled.

P.S.

Also, resolves your issue with the `ComboBox` list getting out of view area.

**UPDATE on issue with `header` element hiding below other list items**:

Accordingly to the description `ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange - the highlight never moves outside of the range. The current item changes if a keyboard or mouse action would cause the highlight to move outside of the range.` when an item goes out of range the list changes next item and that makes `ComboBox` closing its popup, but since header item is below the other `ListView` items itself (see this paragraph https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#stacking-order-in-listview , delegate is always above a header) it makes impossible displaying default header here at the top of the other items. I'd suggest you implement your own header beyond the list. Sorry, I might not have known Qt so good to find the other solution.

Comment: Hi @user3417815,
Thanks for your answer.
I have tried this it is working as expected. But after enabling the **highlightRangeMode** the listview content height is more than the normal mode and we cannot able to see the listview header item. Is there any relation between these two properties?

Comment: @Ramkumar hi, not sure why is that so. I will check on it again.

Comment: I thought to do so, Tried with my own header component rather using the default one with Listview, It works. Thanks for your time.